# g_timeout_add: return value is always 0

Tags: c, glib, gnome, gnome-3

Please look in the below code.

```
guint id = g_timeout_add (5000,(GSourceFunc)fun(), NULL);

bool fun()
{
return false;
}
```

problem 1. The id vale I am getting is always 0.
problem 2. As per the man page [https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add] for the first time, fun() should get call after 5 sec but it is getting called as usual.

Could any one please help me to get the correct id vale and to call the fun() after 5 sec.

I checked the log and below error is showing.

(process:369): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_timeout_add_full: assertion 'function != NULL' failed

I gone through the online documents but didn't get appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass a function pointer to g_timeout_add(), you should not call the function you want to pass:

```
guint id = g_timeout_add (5000,(GSourceFunc)fun(), NULL);
```

As `fun()` return `false`, once casted to `(GSourceFunc)` it's equivalent to `NULL`.

The correct invocation would be:

```
guint id = g_timeout_add (5000,(GSourceFunc)fun, NULL);
```